# form submit jquery v javascript difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit, difference

in javascript this works fine and the validateForm function fires

```
ContactForm = document.getElementById('EmailForm');
ContactForm.onsubmit=validateForm;

function validateForm() {
   //do stuff here
}
```

but why doesnt a similar implementation of the same code in jquery not work? This is what I would like to do

```
ContactForm = $('#EmailForm');
ContactForm.submit=validateForm;

function validateForm() {
   //do stuff here
}
```

after reading http://api.jquery.com/submit/ the following code works

```
ContactForm = $('#EmailForm');
ContactForm.submit(function() {
   //do stuff here
});
```

why does the submit method require a function to wrap around the code im trying to fire. why can i not just call the function directly as native javascript does??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because jquery objects are wrapper around javascript objects. And jquery objects expose another set of methods to work with the underlying javascript objects. `onsubmit` is a property of the underlying javacript object, but jquery object does not have it. When you call

```
ContactForm.submit(function() {
   //do stuff here
});
```

The `submit` function of the jquery object will register the `submit` event for the underlying javascript object

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
var ContactForm = $('#EmailForm');
ContactForm.submit(validateForm());
```

Comment: This does not work. Should change it to ContactForm.submit(validateForm);